# Constructor in a for loop

Tags: java, database, arraylist

I've a beginner at java programming and I've been tasked at creating a database. The database is a bike store with a super class Bike and sub classes mountain bike, road bike. I also have a class called bikeSystem that manages all the subclasses. So far, i've taken the approach of setting up a a constructor in the bike system class, and encapsulating with getter and setter methods. Then tried to create a for loop that sets the size of the database based on the attribute variable for bikesystem "bikes" that specifies the size of the database based on whatever value i change it to. Along with an array list that will create an array of size based on the size of the database.

However, this approach has not worked and i keep receiving errors along the lines of:
BikeSystem.java:18: error: constructor BikeSystem in class BikeSystem cannot be applied to given types;
BikeSystem noOfBikes = new BikeSystem();

As well as a bunch of errors relating to non-static and static contexts.
Any help or insight into this problem, or possible solutions is really much appreciated, thank you for your time.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BikeSystem {
private int bikes;

public BikeSystem(int noOfBikes) {
    bikes = noOfBikes;
}
// Getter
public int getBikes() {
    return bikes;
}
//Setter
public void setBikes(int newBikes) {
    this.bikes = 9;

}   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BikeSystem noOfBikes = new BikeSystem();
    for (int i = 0; i = noOfBikes; i++) {
        ArrayList<Bike> Bike = new ArrayList<Bike>();

    }

}
```

Comment: Constrcutor declared as `public BikeSystem(int noOfBikes) ` but not using it `new BikeSystem();`

Comment: Why would you declared the ArrayList in the loop `ArrayList<Bike> Bike`

Comment: `i = noOfBikes` here it is a integer.  Here `BikeSystem noOfBikes` it is an Object.

Comment: Hint:  You do not need the `int bikes` field and methods, constructor at all

Comment: @ScaryWombat oh ok, so should i just forget about the constructor and set it just as private int = bikesAmount and throw it into the for loop? and for the array list, i'm not too familar on how it works, i just know that it is re sizeable

Comment: see answer below

Comment: *i'm not too familar on how it works,* - this is not a good way to program.  Read about ArrayList, see examples, read the javadocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a `Bike` class with a color propriety,a `BykeSystem` class where you can add lists of bikes,and the `test` class where you make the lists.I made it whithout a for loop.You can create then `MountainBike` class for example that extends `Bike`,add new propriety,like wheight,make a list of them in test class and add it to the `BikeSystem` list:

`BikeSystem` class :

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BikeSystem {

//here you have to add attributes of bikeSystem
    private ArrayList<Bike> bikes;

    public BikeSystem(ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        this.bikes = bikes;
    }

    public ArrayList<Bike> getBikes() {
        return bikes;
    }

    public void setBikes(ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        this.bikes = bikes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BikeSystem [bikes=" + bikes + "]";
    }

}
```

`Test` class:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Bike> Bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();
        Bikes.add(new Bike("red"));
        Bikes.add(new Bike("blue"));
        Bikes.add(new Bike("black"));
        Bikes.add(new Bike("white"));
        ArrayList<Bike> Bikes1 = new ArrayList<Bike>();
        Bikes.add(new Bike("red"));
        Bikes.add(new Bike("blue"));
        Bikes.add(new Bike("black"));
        Bikes.add(new Bike("white"));
        ArrayList<BikeSystem> BikeSys = new ArrayList<BikeSystem>();
        BikeSys.add(new BikeSystem(Bikes));
        BikeSys.add(new BikeSystem(Bikes1));


    }

}
```

`Bike` class:

```
public class Bike {
    //here you have to add attributes of bike
    private String color;

    public Bike(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bike [color=" + color + "]";
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, this is incredible works perfectly! i'm gonna get started into creating the database and all the functions it requires. Again, absolute legend cheers, much appreciated !!

Comment: I am glad i could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution without the fluff would be

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BikeSystem {
private ArrayList <Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<> ();

public void addBike (Bike b) {
    bikes.add (b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int noOfBikes = 9;
    BikeSystem bs = new BikeSystem ();
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfBikes; i++) {
        bs.addBike(new Bike>());
    }

}
```

**Not even tested to see if it compiles**